# Outlook Security, interop NET reference?

Tags: interop, outlook

I am attempting to create a standalone application that accesses Outlook email details.  Specifically the Subject, Sender, and Body of the MailItem.

I cannot for the life of me figure out why sometimes Outlook will prompt the user to allow access (as in, getting the "A program is trying to access email address information....Allow Access for x Minutes message box) and sometimes NOT.  This irregularity is across different attempts at making an application over the weeks, so I am thinking that maybe there is something different with the references I am adding or object use?

I have installed the Microsoft Office 2010 interop assemblies and adding the .NET reference of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook version 14.0.0.0

Here is a very basic snippet of code that does cause the diaglog:

```
using System; <br/>
using System.Collections.Generic; <br/>
using System.Linq; <br/>
using System.Text; <br/>
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook; <br/>

namespace OutlookTest
{
    class Program
   {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application olApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            MAPIFolder oFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

            foreach (object item in oFolder.Items)
            {
                if (item is MailItem)
                {
                    MailItem i = (MailItem)item;

                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", i.Body); 
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: May be of interest: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1thd35d7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You dont do anything wrong, this is outlook security alert which is good for user/company. I had similar issue previous year. Options I remember so far: 
You can create a [trusted microsoft addin](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/327657) as Remou mentioned or you can add yourself as [trusted publisher](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/add-remove-or-view-a-trusted-publisher-HA010034138.aspx) or you can add a visual basic script into Outlook which you can [call from your application](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sachinsancheti/archive/2006/05/16/598951.aspx).

Comment: What I don't understand is what does Office "see" that determines whether an application is trusted or not.  Like I mentioned, in the development process, I have created a few instances where I could access the MailItem.Body without throwing the security pop-up.

Comment: What I believe is those instances were valid after you confirm security popup during the (lets say) 10 minute.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, if Outlook did not detect an antivirus solution installed on the host machine, you would get the "Security Confirmation Prompt" on every code run. You would get it less if you had a commercial solution.

This prompt still comes up today in Office 365, but you can suppress it by changing the "Programmatic Access Security" settings. Below is a before and after.

Before, no "commercial" antivirus solution was installed on the host, initially we got the prompt on every code run. The prompt ceased to surface after we set Programmatic Access Security to "Never warn me about..."

[image: Programmatic Access Security - Not Recommended]

Once the commercial Antivirus Solution was installed the "Antivirus Status" showed up as "Valid".

[image: Installed Commercial Solution]